# Saving images in the filesystem

Tags: spring

I'm currently saving the images as blobs in the db. I've read about saving them in the filesystem. What does that mean exactly? Saving them in the resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can define other disk space / directory for storing images. And then you can store image path in database.

Comment: You mean in the ``main`` directory? For example a folder named ``web-content`` and have a ``images`` inside it?

Comment: Actually not. It can be any directory in filesystem. You can configure directory path in configuration file as property.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add a property to any config/properties file with value as a folder location, some place accessible to the java program like `d:\pictures\`. Useful link: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Then next you get the path via program and save the file to that location. Take care to provide unique names for each file so that there is no overwrite. Then save the file location as string to the database.

This way you can fetch the image from filesystem by using the location string from database and reading the file as `inputstream` for further processing.

Happy Coding!